# React: passing props through a layout component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

new to React here, I want to have a filter (in Nav.js) that filters content on App.js, but  is nested in a Layout component. What's the best way to pass around props here? Can I keep everything as a functional component?

files here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-menu-react-layout-uvppj?file=/src/Layout.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the **setFilter** as **props** and you should be good to go.

```
const Layout = props => {
  const { setFilter, children } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav setFilter={setFilter} />
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: that works!! thank you. wouldn't have thought to pass the function.